# Mac Email @ Startup

Tags: mac, email, boot

How do I send an e-mail when my Mac starts up?

My user account logs in automatically, and the recipient and the content of the mail is the same every time.

Comment: Do you want it to be send *before* a user even logs in, or after?

Comment: Moreover, is the recipient and the content of the mail the same every time?

Comment: My Mac starts up with me logged on and Yes the recipient and the content of the mail are the same every time.

Comment: Anybody have an idea ?

Comment: you can write a script that by means of cron, just after the system is started, calls "mail" and sends the email you want

Comment: user10826 - I'm a fairly new mac user and not familiar with script writing or cron. Any help; sample script, cron info, etc. would be greatly appreciated. Thanks - Avoyager